# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, events

I have the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame({"values":[np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()], 
                  "index":[1992,1993,1994,1995]})

standarderrors1992 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650))
standarderrors1993 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650))
standarderrors1994 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650))
standarderrors1995 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)) 
add1992 = 1.96*standarderrors1992
add1993 = 1.96*standarderrors1993
add1994 = 1.96*standarderrors1994 
add1995 = 1.96*standarderrors1995
mean1992 = np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean()
mean1993 = np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean()
mean1994 = np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean()
mean1995 = np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()
labels = [1992,1993,1994,1995]
add = [add1992,add1992,add1994,add1995]

def onclick(event):
 plt.cla()
 plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
 plt.xticks(labels)
 plt.show()
 limit = event.ydata
 limits = []
 limits.append(limit)
 if len(limits) >= 1:
    plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_disconnect(plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick))
 dict = {mean1992:add1992,mean1993:add1993,mean1994:add1994,mean1995:add1995}
 colourofbars = [] 
 for key,value in dict.items():
    if limits[0] > (key+(value)):
        colour = 1 
        colourofbars.append(colour)
    elif limits[0] < (key-(value)):
        colour = 0 
        colourofbars.append(colour)
    elif (limits[0] < (key+(value))) and (limits[0] > (key-(value))): 
        colour = ((key+(value))-limits[0])/((key+value)-(key-value)) 
        colourofbars.append(colour)
 df["colourofbars"] = colourofbars
 cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
 norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(df["colourofbars"].values),vmax=max(df["colourofbars"].values)). 
 plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,color=cmap(norm(df["colourofbars"].values)),align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)     
 plt.xticks(labels)
 plt.axhline(y=limits[0],linewidth=1, color='k')
 plt.title('Graph showing proportion of confidence interval lying above the threshold value',y=1.05)
 plt.ylabel('Possible Y-threshold values',labelpad=5)
 plt.xlabel('Year',labelpad=5)
 sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
 plt.gcf().colorbar(sm)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/untitled2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<input>", **line 42**, in onclick
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'*
```

Could anyone give me a helping hand?

The overall aim is to allow the user to **select a Y-value by pressing on the bar graph.** The colour of each bar should then change depending on what this Y-value is.

When I enter the code into Pycharm twice in a row, it seems to work, which I find hard to understand? Perhaps there is something wrong with the part where I use .plt to plot the bar graph?

Comment: One thing: in `elif (limits[0] < (key+(value))) & (limits[0] > (key-(value))):` the `&` is a bit-wise operator, and you appear to be using it for logical operations. You should be using `and` instead. As for the Nonetype issue, can you print out the variables involved `limits[0]`, `key`, and `value` to see where you might have a None object?

Comment: @Sam thanks for your help! I have solved my issue and the answer is posted below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the function onclick() by removing these lines and placing them outside the function:

```
plt.cla()
plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.show()
```

Thus, the correct code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame({"values":[np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()], 
                  "index":[1992,1993,1994,1995]})

standarderrors1992 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650))
standarderrors1993 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650))
standarderrors1994 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650))
standarderrors1995 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)) 
add1992 = 1.96*standarderrors1992
add1993 = 1.96*standarderrors1993
add1994 = 1.96*standarderrors1994 
add1995 = 1.96*standarderrors1995
mean1992 = np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean()
mean1993 = np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean()
mean1994 = np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean()
mean1995 = np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()
labels = [1992,1993,1994,1995]
add = [add1992,add1992,add1994,add1995]
plt.cla()
plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.show()

def onclick(event):
    limit = event.ydata
    limits = []
    limits.append(limit)
    if len(limits) >= 1:
        plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_disconnect(plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick))
    dict = {mean1992:add1992,mean1993:add1993,mean1994:add1994,mean1995:add1995}
    colourofbars = [] 
    for key,value in dict.items():
        if limits[0] > (key+(value)):
            colour = 1 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
        elif limits[0] < (key-(value)):
            colour = 0 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
        elif (limits[0] < (key+(value))) and (limits[0] > (key-(value))): 
            colour = ((key+(value))-limits[0])/((key+value)-(key-value)) 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
    df["colourofbars"] = colourofbars
    cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(df["colourofbars"].values),vmax=max(df["colourofbars"].values))
    plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,color=cmap(norm(df["colourofbars"].values)),align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
    plt.xticks(labels)
    plt.axhline(y=limits[0],linewidth=1, color='k')
    plt.title('Graph showing proportion of confidence interval lying above the threshold value',pad=5)
    plt.ylabel('Possible Y-threshold values',labelpad=5)
    plt.xlabel('Year',labelpad=5)
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    plt.gcf().colorbar(sm)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

I am no longer getting the above error message. When I run this code, this figure appears:

[image]

When I then click on this graph, the correct output appears:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In your code somewhere you're trying to compare none value with float

This problem also comes up when migrating to Python 3.

In Python 2 comparing an integer to None will "work," such that None is considered less than any integer, even negative ones:

```
>>> None > 1
False
>>> None < 1
True
```

In Python 3 such comparisons raise a `TypeError`:

```
>>> None > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

>>> None < 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

you need to add a return in your function to get the number you input, otherwise it return an implicit None

This is not as relevant answer but i hope you will get some hint from this

Comment: where should I add the return?

Comment: File "<input>", **line 42**, in onclick  .Actually somewhere in line 42 you're trying to compare a none with float

Comment: you mean like this: if return limits[0] > xyz

Comment: I'm just trying to give you hints why these error usually comes

Comment: thanks for your help, I have solved my issue and the answer is below!

Answer (score 1):

It appears `limits[0]` is None. So something about how you get that limit is not behaving as you intended. I would add an `if not limits[0]` to handle if it is None, and explore how that is coming about.

Now, I notice that you define `limits` inside your function. I believe this is a scoping problem - you should initialize `limits = []` outside the function, so it is available in the later code.

Comment: thanks for your help - Am I right in saying that my code should store the selected Y-value (by pressing on the graph) in the variable limits? Because this is what I want it to do!

Comment: I updated my answer - you need to define `limits` **outside** the `onclick()` handler, so that it will still be available in your later logic.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have solved my issue and the answer is below!